# After Ajax call, the data-table can't reload

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-table

After my Ajax call is successful, I want to reload my bootstrap-table with the new values that return from my php part.

```
<table id="gelirtableid" data-toggle="table" data-url="gelir-getdata.php" data-classes="table table-hover" data-striped="true"
                        data-pagination="true" data-page-list=[20, 40, 75, 100] data-search="true">
                            <thead>
                                <tr >
                                    <th data-sortable="true" data-field="tarih">Tarih</th>
                                    <th data-sortable="true" data-field="Toplam">Toplam</th>                                    
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
</table>
```

my php script that fetches data from mysql

```
<?php 
include "dbcon.php";
if($_POST["gelirtablosecimi"]){
        $gelirtabloadi = $_POST["gelirtablosecimi"];
        $_SESSION["gelirtabloadi"] = $gelirtabloadi;
}

$gelirtabloadi = $_SESSION["gelirtabloadi"];
$gelirgunluktoplam = $db->prepare("select tarih, hasilat + visa + butce_ici + hisse_satis + sosyal_konut + elektrik + haberlesme + iller_bank + diger AS Toplam from $gelirtabloadi");
$gelirgunluktoplam->execute();
$results = $gelirgunluktoplam->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$json = json_encode($results);
echo $json;

 ?>
```

and my Ajax call

```
$("#gelirgetir").click(function() {
                    var gelirtablosecimi = $("#select1").val();
                    if (gelirtablosecimi) {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "gelir-getdata.php",
                            data: {
                                "gelirtablosecimi": gelirtablosecimi
                            },
                            success: function(result) {                                                                
                                notifyUser('success', 'Başarılı!', 'Tablo başarıyla güncellendi');
                                location.reload();
                            },
                            error: function(result) {
                                notifyUser('error', 'Hata', 'error');
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        notifyUser('info', 'Dikkat', 'Tablo seçimi yapmadınız!');
                    }

                });
```

I'm new with Ajax calls, probably the problem is with my ajax part.
As you see, I'm dealing with `location.reload();` after the call is successful. I tried reload `.container` and `#gelirtableid` but nothing worked for me. Basically, when I press the `#gelirgetir` button, it updates one of my session values and my table depends on that session value. After the session value changes and if I reload the page, new values show up but I have to force-refresh the page. I only want to refresh the table. Any suggestion?

Comment: So, what you're doing is you're simply reloading the window.  That won't actually do anything.  If you're going to use AJAX and jQuery, you could empty the table, and reload with the parsed json data.

Comment: that makes sense. how can i implement like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error when i get from above solution is about `JSON.parse()`. `$.each` expects parse the JSON data. Following codes are working like charm.

```
<table id="gelirtableid" data-toggle="table" data-url="gelir-getdata.php" data-classes="table table-hover" data-striped="true"
                            data-pagination="true" data-page-list=[20, 40, 75, 100] data-search="true">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr >
                                        <th data-sortable="true" data-field="tarih">Tarih</th>
                                        <th data-sortable="true" data-field="Toplam">Toplam</th>                                    
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
</table>
```

Ajax call:

```
$("#gelirgetir").click(function() {
                    var gelirtablosecimi = $("#select1").val();
                    if (gelirtablosecimi) {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "gelir-getdata.php",
                            data: {
                                "gelirtablosecimi": gelirtablosecimi
                            },
                            success: function(result) {
                                var content = '';
                                    var obj = JSON.parse(result);
                                    $.each(obj, function(i, data) {                                        
                                        content += '<tr>';
                                        content += '<td>'+obj[i].tarih+'</td>';
                                        content += '<td>'+obj[i].Toplam+'</td>';
                                        content += '</tr>';
                                    });

                                    $('#gelirtableid tbody').html(content);                                                             
                                notifyUser('success', 'Başarılı!', 'Tablo başarıyla güncellendi');                                
                            },
                            error: function(result) {
                                notifyUser('error', 'Hata', 'error');
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        notifyUser('info', 'Dikkat', 'Tablo seçimi yapmadınız!');
                    }

                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your table code so that you have a table body.  We're going to replace this later.

```
<table id="gelirtableid" data-toggle="table" data-url="gelir-getdata.php" data-classes="table table-hover"
       data-striped="true"
       data-pagination="true" data-page-list=[20, 40, 75, 100] data-search="true">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-sortable="true" data-field="tarih">Tarih</th>
        <th data-sortable="true" data-field="Toplam">Toplam</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

In your function, you need to pull the data out of the response via parseJSON function within jQuery.  Then, you need to build your content for your table body.  Here's an example.

```
$("#gelirgetir").click(function () {
    var gelirtablosecimi = $("#select1").val();
    if (gelirtablosecimi) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "gelir-getdata.php",
            data: {
                "gelirtablosecimi": gelirtablosecimi
            },
            success: function (result) {
                notifyUser('success', 'Başarılı!', 'Tablo başarıyla güncellendi');
                var content = '';
                $.each(result, function(i, data) {
                    content += '<tr>';
                    content += '<td>'+result[i].tarih+'</td>';
                    content += '<td>'+result[i].Toplam+'</td>';
                    content += '</tr>';
                });

                $('#gelirtableid tbody').html(content);
            },
            error: function (result) {
                notifyUser('error', 'Hata', 'error');
            }
        });
    } else {
        notifyUser('info', 'Dikkat', 'Tablo seçimi yapmadınız!');
    }

});
```

Comment: my php response is `[{"tarih":"14_03_2018","Toplam":"1516"},{"tarih":"14_03_2018","Toplam":"1524"},{"tarih":"14_03_2018","Toplam":"4625"},{"tarih":"15_03_2018","Toplam":"1512000"}]` and i changed the <td></td> part with `<td>["tarih"]</td>` `<td>["Toplam"]</td>` and nothing changed. any mistake here?

Comment: @KeremCan - I've updated my answer for you.  You should be able to use that now.